# cannot select multiple values reactive form angular

Tags: angular

I am using Angular reactive form in my application.
I would like to set multiple values to a multiple select form control.

mycomponent.html

```
<select id="placeType" 
        class="form-control" 
        [multiple]="true" 
        style="height:200px" 
        formControlName="kalase">
  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select Place Type</option>
  <option *ngFor="let kalase of types" [value]="kalase" [innerHtml]="kalase"></option>      
</select>
```

mycomponent.ts

```
types: string[] = ["BAR", "CAFE", "RESTAU", "hotels", "club"];

this.placeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  kalase: [[this.types[1], this.types[3]]]
});
```

The problem is that the only selected value in select control is the fourth item of types array("hotels"). Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting `kalase` to an array of an array of arrays? Maybe the code should be `kalase: [this.types[1], this.types[3]]`? Remove the first inner array. Too many square brackets?

Comment: I have tried it also...no working either..

Comment: your code is correct, you should multi select by pressing control key when clicking options. (ctrl + left click)

Comment: Easiest way to help people... helping you is to make a repro on stackblitz.

Comment: @Fartab the expected behaviour is "CAFE" and "hotels" already been selected according to my code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

Do not use property binding (brackets `[]`) for `multiple` property:

```
<select id="placeType" 
        class="form-control" 
        multiple
        style="height:200px" 
        formControlName="kalase">

  <option value="" selected disabled>Select Place Type</option>
  <option *ngFor="let kalase of types" 
          [value]="kalase" 
          [innerHtml]="kalase"></option>
</select>
```

**LONGER ANSWER**

Multiple [`select`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_multiple_control_value_accessor.ts#L73) and [`option`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_multiple_control_value_accessor.ts#L179) are Angular directives.
`select` directive iterates over options and decides whether select it or not:

```
this._optionMap.forEach(optionSelectedStateSetter);
```

which calls internal `option`'s function [`_setSelected`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_multiple_control_value_accessor.ts#L218):

```
/** @internal */
_setSelected(selected: boolean) {
  this._renderer.setProperty(this._element.nativeElement, 'selected', selected);
}
```

**In case of `<select [miltiple]="true" ...`**, during this iteration, `multiple` property is not yet rendered on 'select' element (Angular did not evaluate it yet), thus `select` element is treated as single and only last option (in the order of `types` array) is set as `selected`.

Only after this iteration `multiple` property will be rendered by Angular and from this point on, the `select` element will act properly. So even running:

```
setTimeout(this.placeForm.get('kalase').setValue(this.placeForm.value.kalase));
```

would "fix" the problem, because reactive form's model is correct and `select` element now is multiple.

To see incorrect options value, you can run in console:

```
[...document.querySelector('#placeType')].map(x => `${x.value}: ${x.selected}`)
```

which will give you:

```
'': false
'BAR': false
'CAFE': false
'RESTAU': false
'hotels': true
'club': false
```

**In case of `<select multiple ...`**, the element from the very beginning acts as multiple, thus setting option as selected indeed selects them.

Now, running previous debug query will give:

```
'': false
'BAR': false
'CAFE': true
'RESTAU': false
'hotels': true
'club': false
```

If for any reason, you need `multiple` property be conditional, I would recommend to use `*ngIf` or setting default value or values using `setTimeout` along with reactive form's model (as I already demonstrated)

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fz28gx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I don't understand why all the tutorials suggest using FormArray and formArrayName if this solution is way easier.

Comment: you do not need `FormArray` if your model is one dimensional list of primitives (like `[1, 3, 6, 8]` or `['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']` for example). You also can use third party libs' multiselects for this and explore their reactive form examples: https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples, https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect, etc...